# mongodb update multi not working

Tags: mongodb

I'm tying to update a field named company, here is my query

```
user_collection.update({"campaing" => "mediacom"}, {"campaing" => "flatiron"}, {"multi" => true})
```

but the problem is the update affects only one document not all documents from collection and "multi" flag is set to true

Answer (score 1):

Building on what paul referenced in the docs, you want to use a `$set` to change a field value:

```
user_collection.update({ "campaing" : "mediacom" }, { "$set" : { "campaing" : "flatiron" } }, { "multi" : true })
```

Updating with a document means "replace the matched document with this document":

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "a" : 1, "b" : 0 })
> db.test.update({ "_id" : 0 }, { "b" : 1 })
> db.test.findOne()
{ "_id" : 0, "b" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the mongoDB documentation:

"If the  document contains only field:value expressions, then update() cannot update multiple documents."

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: and there are other way to update all documents which meets query

Answer (score 0):

You can try [updateMulti](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-update-document/) function